# taking multiple returns in a function in R in only one command

Tags: r, list, function

I have a function in R, say `TVP()`. It is not my own function and I use it in an R packages about Bayesian simulation. It returns a list of multiple values:

```
tvp<-function(...) {
.
.
.
return(list(A,B,C,...) }
```

Since my function is a simulation function for a large number of iterations, e.g. R=10000 or 50000, its running time is large and also needs more capacity. For instance, in R=50000 it needs 3.5GB if it wants to save all values. I do not need all of the values. For example, I only need A and B.If I use

```
fit<-tvp(...)
A<-fit$A
B<-fit$B
```

it needs a 3 or 4 GB capacity. Also if I use

```
A<-tvp(...)$A
B<-tvp(...)$B
```

no capacity problem, but a huge running time because of two-time call of `tvp` function. I am looking for a simple command that helps me to run the function only one time and without saving all values, it gives me the required values.
Does anyone have an idea? I can prepare a new function which uses the function and returns the values, but I want to know are there better solutions?

Comment: It sounds like the problem is with the `tvp` function, not with how to retrieve the output. If you wrote the function, then consider adding an argument(s) that control what data is included in the output. If not, you may be stuck with either requesting it from the upstream author or rewriting the function locally (to add that functionally ... and then submit as a PR to the author). Either way, the calling environment does not always have the ability to control storage requirements of the function called.

Comment: It's possible to optimize the function to run it faster by vectoriging some calls. If nothing helps, you would want to take a look at `Rcpp` package and rewrite your function.

Comment: It is not my own function. It is a function in an R packages. I can use a function for this reason but I wanted to find a new solution.

Comment: What about `mystuff <- tvp(...)[c("A", "B")]`?

Comment: @Frank  it works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I answer my question based on the @Frank 's comment. If we use a command like  `mystuff <- tvp(...)[c("A", "B")]`, it returns a list, `mystuff`,which contains desired values.